# Using ReactQuery for Search page, need to call multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-query

im hoping this is an easy one for an experienced react query user, but i dont see the solution for using ReactQuery as the fetch mechanism for a search page, where the end user updates the search criteria and executes a new search. i see there is a useQueries, but it states its for multiple parallel queries. im looking for:

- load page without query (no search text)
- user enters search criteria,
- execute search query
- user updates search criteria,
- execute search query again

Comment: This isn't really a question. Maybe reword it so that you're asking specifically how to implement the thing you're trying to make. Then I can answer it for you. (hint: the answer is query keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont't need `useQueries` for this.

```
 const {data} = useQuery(['search',searchTerm],()=>/*search api*/,{
  enabled: !!searchTerm
})
```

- `searchTerm` is passed as queryKey so that whenever it changes a new call to api is made.
- the query is only enabled when `searchTerm` is not empty.